# Finding a number between a maximum and minimum number and generating a random integers in that range

Tags: matlab

I am trying to find the total number of guesses required for finding an integer between a maximum and minimum number by generating random integers in that range from the minimum to maximum until a match of the the number is found.

For example, when I enter `max = 10` and `min = 1` and then I choose say 5 that is between those two numbers, I would like to generate a random number from the range `1:10` until my number of choice of 5 is found and we display a count of the trials to obtain that number. I wrote the following code in MATLAB but I don't understand why it isn't working.

```
minumber = input('Please enter a minimum value: ');
maxnumber = input('Please enter a maximum value: ');
choicenumber = input('Please enter your choice in this range: ');
randnumber = (maxnumber-minumber).*rand(maxnumber,1) + minumber;
i = 1;

while randnumber(i) ~= choicenumber
      tries(i) = randnumber(i);
      i = i + 1;
end
fprintf('It took %d tries to generate your number', i);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have three comments:

1. If your intent is to generate random integers, do not use `rand`.  This generates floating point numbers in the range of `[0,1]` and if you scaled this number so that it confirms to a minimum and maximum range, the floating point errors will prevent you from properly doing an equality comparison.  Check out this canonical Stack Overflow post: [Why is 24.0000 not equal to 24.0000 in MATLAB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/686439/why-is-24-0000-not-equal-to-24-0000-in-matlab).  If you want to generate random integers, use [`randi`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/randi.html) for that instead.  You can actually specify the smallest and largest integer to be generated directly, which is inputted as a two-element array.
2. Inside the `while` loop is where you should be generating the number.  You only generate the number once outside of the `while` loop and this will only exit if you manage to generate the desired number on the first try.  This will hang indefinitely otherwise.
3. Make the `tries` variable just a scalar.  You just want to accumulate how many times it required to guess.  Do the same thing for `randnumber`.  From what I can see in your code, you are not required to remember the history of each guess.

---

With the above comments, do something like this instead:

```
minumber = input('Please enter a minimum value: ');
maxnumber = input('Please enter a maximum value: ');
choicenumber = input('Please enter your choice in this range: ');

randnumber = randi([minumber maxnumber], 1); % Change
tries = 1; % Change

while randnumber ~= choicenumber
      randnumber = randi([minumber maxnumber], 1); % Regenerate number
      tries = tries + 1; % Change
end
fprintf('It took %d tries to generate your number.\n', tries); % Change
```

---

I put the above code into a test script called `test_random.m` and ran it a few times.  Here are some sample runs I ran with your desired inputs:

```
>> test_random
Please enter a minimum value: 1
Please enter a maximum value: 10
Please enter your choice in this range: 5
It took 4 tries to generate your number.
>> test_random
Please enter a minimum value: 1
Please enter a maximum value: 10
Please enter your choice in this range: 5
It took 10 tries to generate your number.
>> test_random
Please enter a minimum value: 1
Please enter a maximum value: 10
Please enter your choice in this range: 5
It took 16 tries to generate your number.
```

Comment: Thanks for the brevity, yes I should have included the random number in the while loop. Thanks